# MGF of $X = \frac{||\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}||^2}{||\mathbf{u}||^2}$

Tags: complex-numbers, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Let $\mathbf{u}=[u_1,u_2,\dots,u_N]^T |\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times 1}$ and $\mathbf{v}=[v_1,v_2,\dots,v_N]^T \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times 1} $ are complex random vectors whose entries $u_i,v_i \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,1)$ .

I am trying to find the MGF of the following expression:
$$X = \frac{||\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}||^2}{||\mathbf{u}||^2}$$
where MGF is defined as
$$\mathcal{M}_X(s) = \int_{0}^\infty e^{sx}f_X(x)\,dx.$$

where $f_X(x)$ is the pdf of $X$. I am looking for the MGF of $X$.

Thank you :)

Comment: The first thing to notice is that $X$ has a fat tailed distribution, with $f_X(x)$ asymptotically behaving like $\frac{1}{x^k}$ for some $k$, so the MGF won't converge when $Re(s)>0$

Comment: So, can I find the value of $k$?

Comment: it's not hard to find $k$, I was just being lazy. It just comes from the $\frac{1}{||u||^2}$ part, which gets very large as $u$ is close to the origin. For an $n$ dimensional normal distribution, the CDF of $||Z||$ will look like $z^n$ near 0, but as this is complex, you have twice the dimensions. The CDF looks like $z^{2N}$, so the CDF of $||Z||^{-2}$ looks like $z^{-N}$ when $z$ is near infinity.

Comment: Hello, can you help me to find the explicit PDF of "X" ?

Comment: I don't know whether there is a close form solution, but I'm not that good at integrals anyway, so I can't help with that I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response :)